# How to achieve Word 2007's "Picture Shape" functionality in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2010

Word 2007 has a very nice feature. When you insert a picture to a document, on the Format tab there is a button labeled "Picture Shape". Pressing it yields a menu of all the standard Word drawing shapes. If you select one, the picture is automatically cropped to that shape. For example, if you choose the heart shape, you get the picture cropped like a heart.

It also interacts nicely with the picture frame selections in the Picture Styles. For example, if you choose the style that looks like a silver picture frame and then change the Picture Shape, the frame automatically adjusts, so you get, for example, a heart-shaped picture frame around the photo. Or a lightning-bolt shaped picture frame. Or whatever. It's nice and easy and encourages experimentation.

Sadly - in Word 2010, the "Picture Shape" button is missing. I've tried searching the Help files and the internet and left-clicked and right-clicked on anything that might be related. The closest I've found is a clumsy procedure that involves inserting a shape & then going into the properties and the going the Fill section, selecting Picture Fill, the opening the picture file and inserting it - and then, if you're lucky you'll have an approximation of what used to take two clicks. But if you want to try other shapes or apply other styles to the picture, or crop it, etc. - you're outa luck. It either isn't available or you have to go back to the start line.

Is there a way to restore or achieve the functionality that I had in Word 2007 with the "Picture Shape" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature seems to be quite easily accessible via the Ribbon:

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks. There it is. Now that I've seen it,  it seems obvious... Why oh why couldn't they have something in the Help system.  I searched on many variations of "Picture shape" but never found this simple answer. Thank you!